# Appending a row to a JavaScript array not working as expected

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a form that can submit a number of rows of data associated with a given date.  One of those fields is a percentage (i.e.: 0-100). I could have three rows of a given date with percentages that add up to 100 (or not, but that's a different validation issue) or two rows with different dates and associated percentages, etc.

I need to keep track of everything and sort all the percentages into the right date buckets on submission so I can do my validation.

To that end, I created an array, PctArray. Each element of PctArray is a two field Object - date, pct. As I loop through submitted data, I check each row's date to see if it's in the PctArray already, and, if so, increment the associated pct field of that date and move on. If not, I create a new element in PctArray and insert the information.

This all works fine and dandy if there's only one row submitted, or even several rows for one date. But the minute I submit information for a second date, it chokes.  At this point, I give you the code:

```
                        // If this is our first row to process

                    if(PctArray.length == 0){
                        PctArray[0] = new Object();
                        PctArray[0].effdt = datefield.options[datefield.selectedIndex].value;
                        PctArray[0].pct = parseInt(pctfield.value); 
                    }
                    else{
                        // We loop through the array to see if this EffDt exists yet. Not very efficient, but the array will always be small
                        var found = "no";

                        for(p=0;p<PctArray.length;p++){
                            if(PctArray[p].effdt == datefield.options[datefield.selectedIndex].value){
                                PctArray[p].pct = PctArray[p].pct + parseInt(pctfield.value);   
                                found = "yes";
                            }   
                        }

                        if(found == "no"){
                            PctArray[PctArray.length] = new Object();
                            PctArray[PctArray.length].effdt = datefield.options[datefield.selectedIndex].value;
                            PctArray[PctArray.length].pct = pctfield.value; 
                        }

                    }
```

The initital take, when it's the first row, everything creates and inserts just fine. But, when I need to go into the block of `if(found == "no")` it creates the new element, but then dies on the first assignment statement saying `Unable to set value of the property 'effdt': object is null or undefined`.

I don't get it. I'm declaring the new element the SAME EXACT WAY in both places, but there's something I'm missing that it's not liking about the second time.

I've also tried replacing `new Object()` with `{"effdt":'', "pct":''}` with identical results. It works on the top one, not the bottom one.

I'm lost.  Does anyone see what I'm missing here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PctArray[PctArray.length] = new Object();
PctArray[PctArray.length].effdt = datefield.options[datefield.selectedIndex].value;
```

After the first assignment `PctArray.length` has increased so you are trying to address non-existing element. You may improve the code by combining your assignments without expllicit `new Object()`:

```
PctArray.push( 
  { effdt: datefield.options[datefield.selectedIndex].value
  , pct: pctfield.value 
  })
```

Comment: OF COURSE!!!!! OMG, I can't believe I missed that!!!  Thank you!!! This is called staring at the issue so long, you miss the obvious! LOL!